# Where can I get a multipoint shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, point

I'm trying to find a multipoint shapefile to do some testing for an application I'm working on, but I cannot seem to find one (and do not have ArcGIS to create one). Can anyone suggest a place to find a sample multipoint shapefile?

Comment: GeoWizards {Demo} Point To Multipoint http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uploaded a part of the dataset I'm working with regularly. Due to user error restrictions, it has to be a multipoint layer instead of just a point one, but most features will have only one point as the multipoint. Anyway, you [can grab it here](http://lynxlynx.info/gis/multipoint.shape.zip). It will stay there for posterity's sake.

In general, you could create it with other software, some free like QGIS, or write it as WKT and use a converter. [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/index.html)/OGR come to mind, but there are also free online versions like [GeoConverter](http://gis.hsr.ch/wiki/GeoConverter).

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I have QGIS, though not sure how to create a multi point from that. But I probably could have created a simple one with GDAL - thanks!

Comment: Actually I don't think QGIS will do it, I just tried creating a point shapefile in QGIS, adding a few points, and merging them. When I tried to save my edits it said I couldn't save a Multipoint feature in a Point layer. But there is no option to specify multipoint geometry when you're creating a shapefile in QGIS.

Comment: Import multipoint WKT as a new layer (Delimited text layer in the menu). You can get dummy data by copy-pasting a few selected values from a point layer to a text editor, running a search&replace and saving it as a CSV.

Comment: Since I downloaded the file and nearly despaired trying to read it: It does not contain MultiPoint (shape type: 8) shapes but MultiPointZ (shape type: 18) shapes. And in addition to that the optional M-values are missing so the ContentLength is 40 words (80 bytes) rather than the expected 64 words (128 bytes). With that in mind it reads fine.

Answer (score 3):

The English Heritage [Listed Buildings Dataset](http://services.english-heritage.org.uk/NMRDataDownload/) is Multipoint.